# ConstraintLayout how to align to center of screen and not to overlap uneven side buttons

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I have a design request to make a text be the center of the screen but not to overlap buttons on the sides. those buttons might appear or not. This is the design:[image: this is the design]

The problem is when the text is long, this bad thing happens:
[image: bad]
But I want it to be like this:
[image: good]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Guideline](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/Guideline) for this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">


<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.4"/>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.6"/>

<View
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline1"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<View
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/guideline2"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="sjkelf hue hwe fhwefh wehwe hwe hwef "
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/guideline1"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/guideline2"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

It looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hi for this problem you should contrast the left and right sides of the text view to the buttons and set the text view size in width to 0dp in the height of wrap_content.

```html
<TextView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="Left Button"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="Right Button" />
```

Comment: No, this won't work since the text is not aligned to the center of the screen.